# не удаётся открыть источник файл "stdafx.h"

Tags: c++

вот код программы,задание-сдвигает число по битам вправо

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        int i, j;
        short x, check = 1, saver3 = -32768;
        cout <<("Введите количество сдвигов\n");
        cin >> j;
        cout << ("Введите число\n");
        cin >> x;
        cout << ("Исходное число в двоичной системе\n");
        for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (x & (check << i)) { cout << 1; }
            else { cout << 0; }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            if (x < 0)
            {
                if (x & check) { x = x >> 1; }
                else { x = x >> 1; x = x + saver3; }
            }
            else if (x > 0)
            {
                if (x & check) { x = x >> 1; x = x + saver3; }
                else { x = x >> 1; }
            }
        }
        cout << endl << ("Полученное число\n ");
        cout << dec << x;
        cout << endl << ("Полученное число в двоичной системе\n");
        for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (x & (check << i)) { cout << 1; }
            else { cout << 0; }
        }
        _getch();
    }
```

Comment: *"Говорил ему Балда с укоризною - не гонялся бы ты, поп, за дешевизною"* (с) Если уж тянете чужие тексты, то... Это стянуто из VC++, проект с предкомпиляцией заголовков. Выкиньте его. Да и набор заголовочных файлов у вас как для С++ - ну очень странный.

Comment: @Harry, я вроде как и пишу на VC++

Comment: В новой студии название по умолчанию поменяли, вроде на `"pch.h"`. Когда проект создавали, надо было посмотреть, какой инклуд там по умолчанию стоял.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 17 студия,поменял,однако та же ошибка,только с "pch.h"

Comment: Пересоздайте проект и посмотрите, что там по умолчанию стоит.

Comment: Будьте проще, просто удалите объявление этого заголовка. А в свойствах проекта, выключить опцию - [precompiled headers](https://corbands.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/отключение-precompiled-header/)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вы всё таки были правы,создал новый проект,тут "pch.h",всё работает,спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ дан в комментарии,пользователем HolyBlackCat,поскольку у меня VC++ 17 года,необходимо было поменять `#include "stdafx.h"` на `#include "pch.h"`.